# Facebook App does not display page when linked from iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I'm working on iOS application. Here is the code i used

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://page/5718758966"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}

else
{
    //Open the url as usual
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://facebook.com/5718758966"]];
}
```

As I mentioned, this code has worked to open Facebook app but shows blank page; my question is if there is an alternative link I can use that will both open the app and direct the user to this specific page, or is this simply a Facebook bug?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "fb://page/5718758966" try "fb://profile/5718758966" for your URL.